# php array_search not giving expected output with number 1

Tags: php

I have a problem with the output of array_search,
with this code, I have to search different ids ($progId) that are located in the column 0 of the multidimentional array $progInLvl . However it wont return a positive result when searching for integer 1, while 2 or 3 are working well.

Do you know where this could be coming from?

Cheers

```
$progInLvl = [[1, "a", "aaaa"], [2,"b", "bbbb"], [3, "c", "cccc"]];    

$progId = 1;
$newArr = array_column($progInLvl, 0);

if (!array_search($progId, $newArr)){
       $progId = "fail";
    } 

echo $progId;
```

Comment: `if (false !== array_search($progId, $newArr)){` read that- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_search()` will return the key.

Doing `if (!array_search($progId, $newArr))` will evaluate to **true** if the returned key is 0. 0 is one of the falsy values.

Use this instead :

```
// triple equal will ensure type and values match
if (array_search($progId, $newArr) === false)
```